# NMEA 2000, configure repetition of messages

Tags: nmea, nmea2000

According to the NMEA 2000 standard it is possible to configure the repetition time of messages which are specified by the manufacturer of the receiver. This is done by the Group Function message (PGN 126208) is sent. Because this message is larger than eight bytes, a transport protocol is needed.My question is, which protocol is used. Is it the TP (SAE J1939), ETP (ISOBUS), Fast Packet (NMEA2000)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The PGN is composed of information from the 29-bit identifier format.  The contents are:

- EDP (Extended Data Page): 1-bit
- DP (Data Page): 1-bit
- PDU-F (PDU-Format): 8-bits
- PDU-S (PDU-Specific): 8-bits

The PGN you provide is 126208 which becomes 0x1ED00.  If you decode the information you see that EDP is 0 and DP is 1.  This is a NMEA2000 message.  Use the Fast-Packet transport protocol.

There's a good primer provided by Vector CANtech here: 
http://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-ION-1-3100_Introduction_to_J1939.pdf

(The DP & EDP bits are discussed on page 4 of that PDF)